# Generate html from Locust Test results

Tags: python-3.x, load-testing, locust

I have a locust test that ran for 6hours and has failed for some unknown reason. I have all the exception, failures, stats, stats history data but my html file was not written.

How can i generate a html from the locust test results?

Answer (score 0):

I think that perhaps in this case you could use this [tool](https://github.com/benc-uk/locust-reporter) to benefit from the data you already have

As explained [here](https://github.com/locustio/locust/issues/1693) there are some issues with the Locust HTML Report

Answer (score 0):

If you don't insist on a HTML report, you could have a look at [JtlReporter](https://github.com/ludeknovy/jtl-reporter), which is an online application for generating performance reports.

Disclosure: I am the author of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Command to generate html file:

```
locust -f .\govern_work\get_request.py -u 1 -r 1 -t 10s --headless --print-stats --host=https://example.com -L DEBUG --logfile demo_report.log --html <your_performance_report_name>
```